# Some text looks strange in BizTalk Orchestration Designer

Tags: visual-studio-2015, biztalk, biztalk-orchestrations

I have an issue with Visual Studio 2015. The text looks strange and all the text is not visible. See attached image. Anyone who knows how to fix this issue? I think I once found a blog where you can add something to the Windows Registry to fix this issue, but I can not find it. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

I have tried to change some theme options in Visual studio, but it didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried re-creating the Logical port in the Orchestration?